# DRF: only Author can create or update the book permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, I have two simple models:

```
class User(AbstractUser, models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(
        'Username', max_length=255,
        db_index=True, unique=True
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        'Email', max_length=255, db_index=True,
        blank=True, null=True, unique=True
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('email', 'password',)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and a serializer like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Book
        fields = ['title', 'author']

    def validate_author(self, author): # < --- it doesn't work
        if author != serializers.CurrentUserDefault():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'You cant update other authors book'
            )


    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(),
        queryset=models.User.objects.all()
    )
```

and a view with some permissions:

```
class IsAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.author == request.user


class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.BookSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly & IsAuthorOrReadOnly]
```

So, how can I ensure that a user can get all of the books but can't create or update the books which don't belong to him?

Comment: code snippet seems fine. What problem are you facing?

Comment: CurrentUserDefault sometimes returns me just a string 'CurrentUserDefault' instead of the actual user. I can't get what the problem here.

Also, to put this particular validation into the serializer sounds a little bit wrong. Maybe there is a better place for it.

Comment: apart from that, how do you plan to create a **`Book`** instance? I don't think we can validate `Book.auther` before the create operation

Comment: we can basically validate that book.author is a current user

Answer (score 3):

This code may be useful if you want to permit Authenticated users to have `SAFE_METHODS` requests and only the Authors to have extra permission to `PUT` and `DELETE`. Unauthenticated users don't have any permission even `GET`. Of course  you should use an inherited class from `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` in view.

```
class IsAuthorOrIsAuthenticated(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
    return obj.author == request.user
```

Here the interesting part for me is that an anonymous user doesn't have any permission but the `GET` `OPTIONS` `PUT` and `DELETE` buttons are available! (However these buttons does not work for him/her!)

I would appreciate it if someone tell me what should I do to remove the buttons for anonymous users.

I will attach my online project here to see the result ...

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I'm working on it and I will correct my comment soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
# serializers.py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Book
        fields = ['title', 'author']
        read_only_fields = ('author',)


# views.py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.BookSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return models.Book.objects.all()
        else:
            return models.Book.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

**References**
1. [**Specifying read only fields** - DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields)
2. [**`perform_create()`** method of APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods)